# 8-layer PCB stackup question

Tags: pcb, stack-up

I'm designing a 8-layer PCB stack up. I have two choices as below:

```
Layer   STACKUP 1    Layer   STACKUP 2   Question related
=========================================================
  1     SIGNAL         1     SIGNAL
  2     GROUND         2     GROUND
  3     SIGNAL         3     SIGNAL
       / / / / /            / / / / /
  4     SIGNAL         4     SIGNAL
  5     POWER          5     POWER
       / / / / /       6     SIGNAL          X
  6     SIGNAL              / / / / /        X
  7     GROUND         7     GROUND          X
  8     SIGNAL         8     SIGNAL          X
```

The `/ / / / /` means there is a relative wider distance (around 0.5mm). The difference of the two choice is the reference plane of L6, closer to PWR plane 5, or closer to GND plane 7. Because I have many power rails, I have to split the PWR plane. So, for continuous transimision impedance, I think may L6 goes closer to L7 will be better than go closer to PWR plane, right?

Comment: I have always been told that you need to have an even number of power planes (including power and ground). And that they need to be mirror image top to bottom. Can you get by with 4 signal and 4 plane layers? If so, I would do signal, plane, plane,signal,signal,plane,plane,signal. You can figure out which planes should be power and which ground.

Comment: Then I may go to 10 layer, the cost will increase :(. And I've done the layout, now I can change the layer stackup only.

Comment: Stackup 2 is not symmetric --- which can lead to warping or other issues.

Comment: I think Stackup 1 is OK. The spacing can be symmetric. Only asymmetry is that layer 4 is a signal layer and layer 5 is a plane layer. Maybe you can make up for it by flooding layer 4 with as much GND copper as possible. Then it will have the same thickness as a plane layer, after the board is fully fabricated.

Comment: Might as well try it before you incur the extra cost of the 10-layer board.

Comment: For impedance control, which one should be better? I think the split of the power plane may degrade it's reference plane function.

Comment: Have you considered distributed capacitance laminates? (Buried Capacitance(tm) or equivalent thin-laminate FR4 technology)  The reduction in bypass caps on an 8 layer design just might be worth it...

Comment: Which layers need impedance control?

Comment: And yes -- which layers are you routing high-speed signals on vs low-speed?  The need for 5 signal layers seems a bit...dubious from my standpoint.

Comment: Referencing is a complex topic. Generally, a power plane is as good as a ground plane for impedance control. BUT, you don't want to route across plane splits (I mean layer 4 traces should not cross splits in layer 5) and you should ideally have bypass capacitors in place for locations where a signal goes through a via and thereby changes reference from POWER to GND.

Comment: @ThePhoton: All signal layers except the bottom layer need impedance control.

Comment: @mkeith: Yes, L4 also refer to L5, because it only has no other plane adjacent. So, I route L4 carefully to avoid crossing the slots in L5. But, I can't do so well with L6, so I consider make L6 to refer to L7.

Comment: Because of the large gap, L6 will reference to L7 GND, not L5 Power. L6 routing is much less critical than L4.

Comment: @mkeith: Yes, I think this is the situation in stackup 1, but in stackup 2, the large gap is between L6 and L7, if I calculate the track width reference to L5, the finished board may not work as expected. So, stackup 1 will be the better choice, right?

Comment: In stackup 2, L4 and L6 will reference to L5, because it is the closest plane. The problem is that the board is very asymmetric, so I am afraid it may have warping. I favor stackup 1 for that reason. You can use trace impedance calculators to figure out the impedance for all the traces.

Comment: *And I've done the layout, now I can change the layer stackup only. – diverger 2 hours ago* - if you've not decided the stackup, you've not finsihed the layout. The layout, widths of tracks, making sure return current breaks in reference planes are linked by capacitors, making sure signals are referenced to the right plane, requires knowing the stackup, if you're using high speed controlled impedance signals. If you're not, then it doesn't matter too much.

Comment: @Neil_UK: Yes. But only change the layer stackup and some track width is not a big work, so before give my gerbers to fab, I want to choose a better stackup.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I'm concerned, Stackup 2 is a no-go, because it's non-symmetric. The upper thick dielectric layer is 3rd from the top, but the bottom thick dielectric layer is 2nd from the bottom. This can cause warping of the finished boards, which will lead to further problems.

So if these are your only two choices, you should choose stackup 1.

> Because I have many power rails, I have to split the PWR plane. So, for continuous transimision impedance, I think may L6 goes closer to L7 will be better than go closer to PWR plane, right?

You don't want your controlled impedance traces to run across a split in the power plane if they're using that power plane for their return current.

If you can arrange your splits to not pass under high speed traces, then you can use the power plane as the return for controlled impedance traces.

If your data rates are not too high (say below 1 Gbps), you can probably get away with passing traces over splits, as long as you provide a capacitive path for the return currents to cross the split as well. This could be a capacitor connecting the two power nets, or capacitors from each of the power nets to ground, located as close as possible to where the trace crosses the split.

Other strategies you might consider:

- Dedicate one or two layers to low-speed signals, so that these don't require controlled impedance.
- Two high speed layers (assuming not **too** high a speed) can share a reference plane if one is used for horizontal routes and the other for vertical (so that traces on the two layers don't run parallel each other for any appreciable distance).

  I've seen this mainly used to have routing on L1 and L2 with ground on L3. Whether this is viable or not also depends how dense the component placement is on the top layer.
- If you really need 5 controlled impedance routing layers, then you may in fact want to pay up for a 10 layer stackup.

Comment: The core chip of the board is FPGA + DDR3, all the DDR3 track routed in the internal layers, so I think the 8L maybe the bottom choice. And the layer count need controlled impedance can't be reduce any more. Hope it will work without going to 10L :).